# How to change content by click jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have blocks on a page and two buttons. I want the next scenario: if I click a button "Show red blocks" nothing happens, because red blocks are already on a page. If I click a button "Show green blocks" - green blocks (large and small) are appeared on a page (red blocks are disappeared). If I click the button "Show red blocks" then red blocks appear instead green blocks.

Code does not work correctly and there is an error. I can't manage what is the problem. I've read about innerHtml, but I think it is useless in my case.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-green').click(function showred() {
    $('.block-green').toggleClass('show');
    $('.block-red').toggleClass('hide');
  });

  $('.btn-green').click(function showgreen() {
    $('.block-green-small').toggleClass('show');
    $('.block-red-small').toggleClass('hide');
  });


  $('.btn-red').click(function() {
    $('.block-green').toggleClass('hide');
    $('.block-red').toggleClass('show');
  });

  $('.btn-red').click(function() {
    $('.block-green-small').toggleClass('hide');
    $('.block-red-small').toggleClass('show');
  });

});
```

```css
.container-large {
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px auto 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.container-small {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px auto 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
.btn-red {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn-red {
  background-color: red;
}
.btn-green {
  background-color: green;
}
.block-red {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
.block-green {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
}
.block-red-small {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
.block-green-small {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn btn-red" onclick="showgreen()">Show red blocks</div>
<div class="btn btn-green" onclick="showred()">Show green blocks</div>

<p>Large blocks:</p>
<div class="container-large">
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-green"></div>
</div>

<p>Small blocks:</p>
<div class="container-small">
  <div class="block-red-small"></div>
  <div class="block-green-small"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Run the snippet. The error will tell you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: You need to learn about scope in Javascript. You have defined your functions `showRed` and `showGreen` inside another function. This makes them locally available, but not globally. Define your functions outside your `$(document).ready()`-handler and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive an error because you are calling functions that don't exist:

`onclick="showgreen()"`

You also shouldn't use `toggleClass` in this case else both buttons will hide or show both colours.

You can also combine some of your event listeners together so that you only need two `click()`'s.

Simplified example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-green').click(function showred() {
    $('.block-green, .block-green-small').addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
    $('.block-red, .block-red-small').addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
  });

  $('.btn-red').click(function() {
    $('.block-red, .block-red-small').addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
    $('.block-green, .block-green-small').addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
  });

});
```

```css
.container-large {
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px auto 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.container-small {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px auto 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
.btn-red {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn-red {
  background-color: red;
}
.btn-green {
  background-color: green;
}
.block-red {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
.block-green {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
}
.block-red-small {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
.block-green-small {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn btn-red" >Show red blocks</div>
<div class="btn btn-green">Show green blocks</div>

<p>Large blocks:</p>
<div class="container-large">
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-green"></div>
</div>

<p>Small blocks:</p>
<div class="container-small">
  <div class="block-red-small"></div>
  <div class="block-green-small"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using jquery onclick, no need to define a `javascript onclick` event with it.
Since you have defined a function name `showred()` in `javascript onclick` event but there is not function with such a name it gives you an error.

In order o show or hide your blocks you can use the jquery `.show()` and `.hide()` functions and define the click  event with a single selector just once.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-green').click(function () {
    $('.block-green').show();
    $('.block-red').hide();
  });



  $('.btn-red').click(function() {
    $('.block-green').hide();
    $('.block-red').show();
    
  });

 

});
```

```css
.container-large {
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px auto 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.container-small {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px auto 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
.btn-red {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn-red {
  background-color: red;
}
.btn-green {
  background-color: green;
}
.block-red {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
.block-green {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
}
.block-red-small {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
.block-green-small {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn btn-red" >Show red blocks</div>
<div class="btn btn-green" >Show green blocks</div>

<p>Large blocks:</p>
<div class="container-large">
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-green"></div>
</div>

<p>Small blocks:</p>
<div class="container-small">
  <div class="block-red-small"></div>
  <div class="block-green-small"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your class names a bit, you can make this much simpler and shorter with something like the below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.change-color').click(function () { 
        $(this).hasClass('red') ?
          $('.container .block').addClass('red').removeClass('green'):
          $('.container .block').addClass('green').removeClass('red');
          
  }); 
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px auto 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.container.small {
  max-width: 200px;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
.btn.red {
  margin-bottom: 5px; 
}
.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.block{ 
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.red{  
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn red change-color">Show red blocks</div>
<div class="btn green change-color">Show green blocks</div>

<p>Large blocks:</p>
<div class="container large">
  <div class="block red"></div> 
</div>

<p>Small blocks:</p>
<div class="container small">
  <div class="block red"></div> 
</div>
```